# Django not syncing with sqlite3 (official polls tutorial)

Tags: python, django, sqlite, ubuntu-18.04

So I'm following the official tutorial (creating a polls app) for django and I'm having db issues. For some reason I didn't have sqlite3 included with python (not a big issue, I just installed it). After installation, I have a connection in settings.py like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I ran python migrate.py migrate. The next step was to run sqlite3 and do this:

```
.schema
```

Nothing shows up, because no DB exists. I'm very confused as to what I may not be doing right (or what I have done to mess it up) to get a proper database connection for the app.

Comment: You shouldn't just "run sqlite". You need to tell it what db to open; ie `sqlite3 path/to/db.sqlite3`, or better `./manage.py dbshell`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me. If you could create an answer I'll choose that for any other newbies with the same issue (a lot of my friends has this issue as well).

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is a file-based db, so you need to tell it what database file to open. Either do it explicitly:

```
sqlite3 path/to/db.sqlite3
```

or, better, use Django's shortcut:

```
./manage.py dbshell
```